# Why does 11 not printed from a string in this Python script?

Tags: python, string

There is a Python question like this:

```
>>> import string
>>> s = ‘mary11had a little lamb’
>>> print s
mary had a little lamb
```

Actually when I try it myself, the result is not that, but:

```
mary11had a little lamb
```

Is there anything I don't know about Python that can make 11 disappear from a string?

Comment: Your code would error as posted

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, since the character you are using to enclose the text gives in python 2.7 and 3.5 a syntax error. Which python version are you using? Anyways, use `'` or `"` for strings. Also you don't need to import `string`.

Comment: The only way you would not see 11 is if the string was like  `"mary\11had a little lamb"` but you would see extra whitepace

Comment: Actually, it's a question from a Python test. The correct answer says that is the answer, but when I try it myself the answer is not the same. I am asking here to make sure

Comment: That's it @PadraicCunningham, it was a typo in the test QA web! Thank you so much!

Comment: @tamasgal yup, you are right. But somehow the question makes it that way. A trap maybe

Comment: No worries,  `\11` is a vertical tab. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Padraic has pointed out in the comments - it looks like the leading backslash is missing before the 11 as a minor typo in the question.

So it should read

```
>>> import string
>>> s = ‘mary\11had a little lamb’
>>> print s
mary    had a little lamb
```

It's interpreting \11 as the escape sequence for a numerically defined ascii character, which in this case is horizontal tab (\t). As without qualification, `\nnn` is assumed to be octal (as opposed to `\xnn` which is interpreted as hexadecimal).

So if you were to write just `>>> s` in the REPL, you'd expect it to evaluate to `'mary\thad a little lamb'`.

Same outcome if you entered: `'mary\x09had a little lamb'`